# Nav Menu Drop Down Will Not Display Vertically

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, nav

I cannot figure out why the first tier(Pictures and Videos) drop down menu displays horizontally. I've tried many different things but just cannot figure this out. The 2nd tier(Portraits, Landscapes,abstract) displays vertically.

I'm still new to all this so I'm sure it is a easy fix. Any help will be very much appreciated.

```css
/* Navigation Menu */
.nav  {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0 15px;
 float: right;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: rgba(256, 256, 256,.25);
}
 li{
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-top: 10px;
 }

 
 li a {
  display: block;
  color: rgb(0,0,0);
  padding: 5px 16px 15px 16px;
  font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
 }

 li a:hover { 
  color: #000000;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #000000;
 } 
 li > .gallerydrop, .picturesdrop {
  display: none; 
 }
 li:hover > .gallerydrop {
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgba(256, 256, 256,.25);
 } 
 li:hover > .picturesdrop {

  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgba(256, 256, 256,.25);
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="nav.css" type="text/css">
<title>Nav</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<nav> 
 <ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>  
  <li><a href="aboutme.html">About Me</a></li> 
  <li><a href="details.html">Details</a></li> 
  <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
         <ul class="gallerydrop">
             <li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>
          <li><a href="pictures.html">Pictures</a>
           <ul class="picturesdrop">
                      <li><a href="portraits.html">Portraits</a></li>
                      <li><a href="landscapes.html">Landscapes</a></li>
                      <li><a href="abstract.html">Abstract</a></li>
           </ul>
           </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
       
  <li class="li"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li> 
 </ul> 
</nav>
</html
```

Answer (score 0):

You are applying `float: right` to all `li` elements, but you obviously don't want that. So the trick is to target just the top level `li`s, with something like `.nav>li {float:right;}`.

```css
/* Navigation Menu */
.nav  {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0 15px;
 float: right;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: rgba(256, 256, 256,.25);
}

.nav>li {float:right;}
 li{
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-top: 10px;
 }

 
 li a {
  display: block;
  color: rgb(0,0,0);
  padding: 5px 16px 15px 16px;
  font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
 }

 li a:hover { 
  color: #000000;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #000000;
 } 
 li > .gallerydrop, .picturesdrop {
  display: none; 
 }
 li:hover > .gallerydrop {
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgba(256, 256, 256,.25);
 } 
 li:hover > .picturesdrop {

  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: rgba(256, 256, 256,.25);
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="nav.css" type="text/css">
<title>Nav</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<nav> 
 <ul class="nav">
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>  
  <li><a href="aboutme.html">About Me</a></li> 
  <li><a href="details.html">Details</a></li> 
  <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
         <ul class="gallerydrop">
             <li><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>
          <li><a href="pictures.html">Pictures</a>
           <ul class="picturesdrop">
                      <li><a href="portraits.html">Portraits</a></li>
                      <li><a href="landscapes.html">Landscapes</a></li>
                      <li><a href="abstract.html">Abstract</a></li>
           </ul>
           </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
       
  <li class="li"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li> 
 </ul> 
</nav>
</html
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Those little things that I am looking over. Thank You. This was bothering me so much.